# Friend template function instantiations that match parameter

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, friend

I have a template class that should have a friend: a `make_object` function that allows to deduct certain types and values. I wish to make friends only those instantiations that match the types of the template class. The simplified version of my code is below:

```
template<size_t S, typename T>
class Object {
private:
    Object(T t);

    template<typename U, typename... Args>
    friend auto make_object(U, Args... args);
};


template<typename U, typename... Args>
inline auto make_object(U u, Args... args)
{
    constexpr size_t S = sizeof...(Args);
    return std::unique_ptr<Object<S, U>>(new Object<S, U>(u));
}
```

Taking this code as an example I wish to make friends only those instantiations of `make_object` whose `typename U` matches the `typename T` of the object. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is simply befriending a function template with the same template parameter as `T`, then this would be sufficient:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
auto make_object(T, TArgs...);

template<std::size_t size, typename T>
class Object {
private:
    Object(T t);
    friend auto make_object<T>(T);
};

template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
auto make_object(T t, TArgs... args) {
    Object<0u, T>{t};   // Compiles
}

template <>
auto make_object<float>(float f) {
    // Error: Constructor is private
    Object<0u, int>{static_cast<int>(f)};  
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/BfFCzV)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class to separate the `U` parameter of `make_object` (which has to match with the `T` of `Object`) from the `Args` parameter pack, which does not have to match. Then, befriend the helper class, giving all instantiations of your function access to the `private` members of `Object`.

```
template<typename U>
struct make_object_t;

template<std::size_t S, typename T>
class Object {
private:
    Object(T t);

    friend class make_object_t<T>;
};

template<typename U>
struct make_object_t {
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto make_object(U u, Args... args) {
        constexpr std::size_t S = sizeof...(Args);
        return std::unique_ptr<Object<S, U>>(new Object<S, U>(u));
    }
};
```

Finally, write a helper function to hide the class from the API:

```
template<typename U, typename... Args>
auto make_object(U&& u, Args&&... args) {
    return make_object_t<U>::template make_object<Args...>(std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Now, e.g. this works

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Object<3, int>> ptr = make_object(5, 'a', 0x0B, "c");
}
```

But, e.g. `make_object_t<char>` cannot use `Object<S, int>::Object`:

```
template<>
struct make_object_t<char> {
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto make_object(char u, Args... args) {
        constexpr std::size_t S = sizeof...(Args);
        return std::unique_ptr<Object<S, int>>(new Object<S, int>(u));
    }
};
int main() {
    // error here from instantiation of above function template
    auto oops = make_object('n', 'o');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a friend template, you can make all the instatiations of the template a friend, like in your example, or you can make a full specialization a friend.

There is nothing in between unfortunately.

To work around that you could wrap your `make_object` function in a template class and make that template class a friend.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename U>
struct object_maker;

template<std::size_t S, typename T>
class Object {
private:
    Object(T) {}

    friend struct object_maker<T>;
};


template<typename U>
struct object_maker
{
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto make_object(U u, Args... args)
    {
        constexpr std::size_t S = sizeof...(Args);
        return std::unique_ptr<Object<S, U>>(new Object<S, U>(u));
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto obj = object_maker<int>::make_object(7);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(obj), std::unique_ptr<Object<0,int>>>);
}
```

Comment: I think this is my answer?

Comment: Time machines are a terrifying threat to our society :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `make_object()` is a convenience function template that takes advantage of template argument deduction for creating `Object` objects.

You can create an additional function template, e.g., `create_object()`, that corresponds to the same template parameters as the `Object` class template: `size_t` and a *type template parameter*. Then, you can easily grant friendship in `Object` to an instance of this function template that has the same template arguments as `Object`:

```
template<size_t, typename>
class Object;

template<size_t S, typename T>
inline auto create_object(T t) {
   return std::unique_ptr<Object<S, T>>(new Object<S, T>(t));
}

template<size_t S, typename T>
class Object {
private:
    Object(T t);
    friend auto create_object<S, T>(T);
};
```

Your original `make_object()` function template just delegates to this new function template, `create_object()`:

```
template<typename U, typename... Args>
inline auto make_object(U u, Args... args)
{
    constexpr size_t S = sizeof...(Args);
    return create_object<S, U>(std::move(u));
}
```

Once you know the number of elements in the parameter pack `Args`, you don't need the parameter pack any longer. You only pass the deduced `U` and the calculated `S` as template arguments to `create_object()`.