# C++: Can a Template be friend of a Class?

Tags: c++, templates, friend-class

Is it possible to make friend of a class, all possible variants of a class-template?

Just to clarify, for example, something like this:

```
class A
{ friend template B; }    // syntactic error yeah
```

So any `B<X>` variant could manipulate any protected attribute of `A`.

`A` is an small and simple class with a lot of friends who manipulate its attributes. Just one of then need to be a template. I know that I can do this:

```
template <class T>
class A
{ friend class B<T>; }
```

But so I would have to change my code in all the other friends and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: What sort of template is B? Can you show some example usage?

Comment: *"A is an small and simple class with a lot of friends who manipulate its attributes"*. Maybe all its members should be public?

Comment: @cigien: all the friend are well-know an confiable classes, so inside them A's attributes are safe. But I don't know about other applications who use my entire system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may define a friend template class like that:

```
class A{
    template<typename T>
    friend class B;
};
```

That would make every specialization of `class B` a friend of `class A`. I've had a similar question that had the opposite goal: to restrict some specializations: [Friend template function instantiations that match parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111863/friend-template-function-instantiations-that-match-parameter)